# Find limit of $\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}\cos(in)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the limit of : 
$\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}cos(in)$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

What I did : 
$\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}\cos(in)=\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}(e^{i^2n}+e^{-i^2n})/2=\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty}(e^n+e^{-n})/2=(\infty+0)/2=\infty$ 
But that doesn't seem to be true, because cosine must be between $-1$ and $1$. I used the fact that $\cos(x)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$. What did I do wrong and how can I find the right answer ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: $\cos z$ is unbounded for $z \in \mathbb C$

Comment: Cosine forcomplex arguments is rarely between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: So would my answer still be correct ?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I don't think the "algebra-precalculus" tag is appropriate.

Comment: @Poujh are you assuming n\in \mathb{R}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\cos{ix}=\cosh x\to \infty$$

whereas, more in general, for $z\in \mathbb{C}$

$$\lim_{|z|\rightarrow\infty}cos(iz)$$

does not exist.

Comment: That is true if $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but is not generally true if $x\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: yes I mean of course $ x\in \mathbb{R}$ since in the OP n was handled as an integer or real number, can we give a meaning to the limit also for $ x\in \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: The OP never said that $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  In fact, the limit has $|n|\to\infty$, which might suggest that $n\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I may ask a clarification, I ve interpreted $n\to \pm \infty \implies |n|\to \infty$

Comment: And you might be correct.